# Running Python Script with Launchd: imports not found

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, launchd

I've been trying to set up a script to run a python program at regular intervals using `launchd`. The python program fails because it can't find my imports---I know this because I caught the errors in a log file. To fix this problem, I created `~\.MacOSX\environment.plist`, and duplicated my `PYTHONPATH` there, logged out and logged in again. This seems to be insufficient to solve the problem, and I'm at a loss as to what else to try.

I'm running OSX, 10.8.3.

Related threads:

- [launchd executes python script, but import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573538/launchd-executes-python-script-but-import-fails) (not applicable--my script points to the right python instance)

UPDATE:

It appears that I can run the following command:

```
launchctl setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH
```

and the script will execute successfully. So, to modify my question:

1. Where does this get stored? I checked `~\.launchd.conf` and `\etc\.launchd.conf`, neither existed.
2. Presumably this setting is dumped when I reboot. Where can I change this information so that `launchd` will find it?

Comment: Are we exporting the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: What do you mean exporting? Where do I export it to? (PS: See the update.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the environment of a specific job you should use the `EnvironmentVariables` key in the job definition itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.app</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/your/script</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PYTHONPATH</key>
        <string>/your/python/path</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You may define default environment variables for `launchd(8)` services by editing `/etc/launchd.conf` for daemons or `/etc/launchd-user.conf` for agents. The latter one works but is not documented. The currently documented (but unsupported) per-user config file is `$HOME/.launchd.conf`.

These config files contain a list of `launchctl(1)` subcommands. The one you want is:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH /your/python/path
```

*Update:* `/etc/launchd.conf` is not supported in Mac OS X 10.10 and higher. On these systems you'll have to define environment variables on a per-job-basis.

Comment: Isn't there a way to set it once, in one place, rather than having to tell every plist about it?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to globally define environment variables for `launchd(8)` jobs.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above actually worked for me (OS X 10.11.3). The breakthrough was reading this [script runs fine in terminal but not from launchd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532824/script-runs-fine-in-terminal-but-not-from-launchd/28532848#28532848) and realizing belatedly that one can write the absolute full path to the version of python with the right modules. D'oh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.app</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <string>/path/to/your/python</string>
    <string>/path/to/your/script</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```